# Adding .change to multiple select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

The test case is I've a table in a form. The rows are generated dynamically. Right now with plain html + javascript I've like this,

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="brand_1" name="brand[]" onchange="brandChanged(1)">
            //some options
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="model_1" name="model[]">
            <option>Default Value</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="brand_2" name="brand[]" onchange="brandChanged(2)">
            //some options
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="model_2" name="model[]">
            <option>Default Value</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the `brandChanged(x)` method is triggered it gets the options from another file with an ajax request and adds them to `model_x` select element.

Everything is working fine, but my question is how to do it with jQuery? I mean what's the way to bind `.change()` to these input elements Also I don't like naming ids in `name_id` way. Is there a better design to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Add a common class to all.

**2)** remove inline `onchange` event and write jquery event

**3)** you can put the value in html5 data attribute:

```
<select id="brand_1" name="brand[]" class="brand" data-brand="1">
            //some options
</select>

<select id="brand_2" name="brand[]" data-brand="2">
           //some options
</select>
```

and write event on class:

```
$(".brand").change(function() {

  var brand = $(this).data("brand");
  // do something

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be another approach.
http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/5Lkfh558/

1. `.on()` is used because you mentioned `tr`s are generated dynamically.
2. design implemented without `id`s

**js**

```
$(".mainTable").on("change", ".brand", function () {
    var dataFromAjax = callAjax($(this).data("idx"));
    $(this).parent().siblings().eq(0).find(".model").html($("<option>DATA from AJAX</option>"));
});
```